# JWT token signature validation javascript

Tags: javascript, security, jwt

I was making a javascript client that connects to an Api using JWT tokens. On the server side there are no problems, I can create the token sign it and later verify the signature en thus ensure that nobody tampered with the token.

But how do I do this on the client side. I can just decode the JWT token and see the header, payload and signature. But how do i verify the signature at the client site? Are there libraries for this, how do I transfer the public key to the client?

If I do not verify the signature how can I know the token is not tampered with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if I do not validate the signature at the client side how can I ensure that the token is indeed from the server.? Maybe there is somebody in the middle who is changing the token

**Signature validation does not avoid a Man In The Middle attack**. An attacker could sniff the channel to capture credential or alter messages even using valid tokens

Use a **SSL/TLS channel (https)**

---

> If I do not verify the signature how can I know the token is not tampered with?

A token provided by a TLS trusted server is *probably* valid.(it could has been altered in local storage). You can validate the signature. This operation is usually done in server side( see @sakuto answer), but you can do it in the browser perfectly

> But how do i verify the signature at the client site?

These are the steps

1. Download the public key from a trusted server
2. extract the signature from JWT and decode it( base64url)
3. verify the digital signature using a cryptographic library

I suggest to use the Webcrypto. See an example of RSA import key an validation here: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/blob/master/README.md#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5

Comment: How does SSL help with a man in the middle attack? If the attacker has a valid certificat I would just trust the man in the middle as being the server. I On the other hand the man in the middle does not have the private key needed to sign the JWT token. If I therfore validate the token I would see that the token is not from the correct server.

Comment: Using SSL/TLS the client/browser has a truststore with the accepted Certificate Authorities. **An attacker can not present a valid certificate for your hostname** because a trusted CA will not issue it and if he tries to generate a fake certificate then the client will reject it because the issuer certificate is not present in the truststore.

Comment: As I said in the answer, with a MITM attack (without HTTPS) and attacker could capture a valid token coming from the trusted server and use it to perform fraudelent operations. **The attacker does not need to alter the token to use it**, because the stolen token is valid . With any authentication system you must protect the channel to avoid this

Answer (score 2):

You are usually not doing verification on client-side, nor storing important data on the token. Every control and permission are checked on the back-end. Meaning that even if the user tamper its token, he won't able to pass the back-end control, only possibly seeing one more option on the front.

Comment: But if I do not validate the signature at the client side how can I ensure that the token is indeed from the server.? Maybe there is somebody in the middle who is changing the token. What is the use of checking the issuer if I cannot ensure the token is valid. Or maybe somebody is intercepting my traffic and posing as the server. I now trust the 'fake' server and I just send him my credit card account numbers

Comment: @Arno - On client side, we usually simply parse / decode payload ( not decrypt ) and validate token expiry. This is being done to avoid unnecessary token calls. Actual token validation for tampering etc should happen on server side.

Answer (score 0):

This type of work-around comments are the reason why I don't trust "libraries" written by others.

JWT.io has reported that many of the libraries that are widely available have security vulnerabilities.

RFC 7519 clearly states that the application MUST validate the token signature and if its signature is not valid, you MUST discard it.

Comment: True, but, 'application' here can mean server side, not necessarily client side. 

If a token is invalid client side, the server must absolutely still validate without the client requiring validation. Client should just be passing the jwt's along to allow auth on the server. Validation must always happen on the server.